# OR searching with jquery-datatables

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I'm not sure if I'm not getting my regex correct or if I'm not understanding how to get datatables to accept my search.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zatvo506/2

I am trying to be able to filter/search on column 1 (Date / Time) so that when I click Search 1 both records are shown.

in a nutshell, I'm trying to figure out the correct way to this:

```
data_table.column(1).search('01|02', true, true).draw()
```

and have all rows with either 01 or 02 be shown.

In my fiddle, only the row containing 01 is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong... Even if the updated Fiddle looked convincing.

You were correct with `.search('01|02', true, true)` or `.search('REC|SHP', true, true)`

There are 4 possible arguments:

1. (string - mandatory) The search string
2. (boolean - optional, default:false) **Treat the search string as a Regex**
3. (boolean - optional, default:true) "Smart search"
4. (boolean - optional, default:true) Case incensitive

[Reference for more](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

So... There is no need to actually format it a a "real" regex... The second argument takes care of it.

*You made me learn something new about DataTables here! Thanks!*

Now, I scratched my head quite a time and hallucinated gremlins since the search seamed to work oddly...

I finally noticed the CDN you are using:

> https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css

I replaced it with:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

(*Also changed the .css CDN.*)
And the gremlins all dissapeared... See this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YRwrVW?editors=1010). So I think that should be your solution.

I can't explain much... The [release notes](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/#Release-notes) aren't very detailled.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because it fixed the question I was asking, but if I update it to work on column 0 it still doesn't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/fhgmyo05/

Comment: Oh, I changed it to be /(REC|SHP)/ which is what's not working

Comment: mmmm... Interesting... Hold on.

Comment: I completely changed my answer... Hoping it will fix the issue on your side ;)

Comment: wow! interesting. I'll dig into it some more. Thanks for your help. The CDN link comes from DataTable's download builder. I have a couple of things rolled in. (BootStrap4 and the Responsive plugin) I wonder if that's causing the issue. I'll probably try to narrow it down and then open an issue on github.